# Searching USB cable with 4-pin connector

Tags: connector, components, cables

I am trying to find this USB-A-to-4-pin-connector-cable, which is used quite widely for those USB 2.0 camera modules, [e.g. this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33041088035.html). I need that cable to be longer than the one they ship, something around 1.5 m.

How do I proceed finding it? I am searching Mouser for USB cables, using Google image search etc. But as USB is such a wide term, there is no luck.
If I could identify the connector, I could think about crimping it to the cable myself, to start with.

The measures of the connector are:

- Pitch: 2.0 mm
- Female connector dimension (on the cable): 8.6 x 4.2 mm
- Male connector dimension (on the PCB): 10.0 x 4.8 mm

Following some pictures. I would be really happy about any type of clue! And also, which methods I could apply, searching a component like this. Thanks!

[image: the cable with both ends]
[image: side A closeup]
[image: side A closeup 2]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget all that. Just get a USB-A male to USB-A female extension. If you want it to be more permanent then put some heatshrink around where the two cables mate.

But if you really want to know, my bet would be one of JST's 2.0mm "Wire to Board Crimp Style Connectors. Possibly the PH (**EDIT:** actually now that I look at the other 2.0mm pitch connectors, it's definitely the PH).

http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199

[image]

I found this by going to JST's website and "Searching By Application or Series" and then choosing "Wire to Board Crimp Style Connectors" and then finding the part of the list where the 2.0mm pitch was located and looking at the images. Took about 5 minutes. Would take much longer for someone unfamiliar since their website sucks which seems to be par for the course for most connector manufacturers but JST is especially bad even by their standards.

To make use of this you would need to get a USB-A on one end and "bare wire" or "no connector" on the other end from Mouse or Digikey so you can crimp to it.

Comment: Or get a normal USB cable, cut the appropriate end off, and install the new connector.

Comment: Wow, very good finding! Thanks a lot!
Well the USB extension doesn't work, because there is no space. This is also part of an installation, not one time use. Any idea how to figure out what equipment I'd need for crimping? Those crimpers are usually very expensive, right?

Comment: @Janos Don't buy an official crimper. Get a Crimpall one from GreenLee or one from Engineer Japan